# Html.dropdownlistfor selectedValue not working for page with multiple dropdownlistfor on it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building a web app with multiple tabs that contain data pertaining to a client. On the address tab, it displays additional tabs separating the different addresses for the client such as billing, physical, and mailing addresses. When trying to edit the information, the address type dropdownlistfor won't default to the currently selected type that is loaded for each address. I've tried multiple ways of accomplishing this, but currently I'm getting the following error:

System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'

ViewModel:

```
public class ClientVM
{
    public ClientVM()
    {
        Appts = new List<Appt>();
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
        Contracts = new List<Contract>();
        Depts = new List<Dept>();
        Phones = new List<Phone>();
        Addr_Types = new List<SelectListItem>();
        States = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string client_Name { get; set; }

    public bool is_active { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IList<Appt> Appts { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IList<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IList<Dept> Depts { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Addr_Types { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
    // GET: Clients/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Client client = new Client();
        client = await db.Clients.FindAsync(id);
        if (client == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ClientVM clientvm = new ClientVM();
        clientvm.Id = client.Id;
        clientvm.client_Name = client.client_Name;
        clientvm.is_active = client.is_active;
        clientvm.Addresses = client.Addresses;
        clientvm.Depts = client.Depts;
        clientvm.Contracts = client.Contracts;
        clientvm.Addr_Types = new SelectList(db.Address_Type, "Id", "addr_Type");
        clientvm.States = new SelectList(db.States, "Id", "name");
        return View(clientvm);
    }
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Addresses[y].addr_Type_Id, new SelectList(Model.Addr_Types, "Id", "addr_Type", Model.Addresses[y].addr_Type_Id), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlAddr-" + @y })
```

Comment: You have a model with `List<SelectListItem> Addr_Types` but your view is  using a `ViewBag` property (which you don't even seem to assign in the GET method). Show your real code!

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Like I said I've tried numerous ways and forgot to change that back to using the Model instead of the ViewBag. I edited the above code to reflect the current situation that still doesn't work.

Comment: The message is self explanatory - it needs to be `new SelectList(Model.Addr_Types, "Value", "Text", Model.Addresses[y].addr_Type_Id)` but what you should be doing is making  the model property `IEnumerable<Address> Addr_Types` and using the code you were before (there is no point creating one `SelectList` and then creating another one from it)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stephen Muecke! That worked. I actually had it passing the selectList and using just Addr_Types, but could not get the selectedValue to work and the only way I could get close was using the new SelectList again. Thanks for pointing out that casting it again, then changed to "Value" & "Text".

Comment: As I noted, the better way is to make the property `IEnumerable<Address> Addr_Types` and in the GET method `clientvm.Addr_Types = db.Address_Type,` and then use the code you originally had (its just extra overhead to be creating a `SelectList` in the controller)